# DataBinding: 'ToShortDateString()' is not a valid indexed expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, repeater

I have one Repeater

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="repID" runat="server">
           <ItemTemplate>
                 <tr>
                       <td>
   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DateCreated.ToShortDateString()")%>
                       </td>
                       <td>
   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Comment")%>
                        </td>
                </tr>
           </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want to show field DateCreated ToShortDateString(), but it gives me this error:

```
DataBinding: 'ToShortDateString()' is not a valid indexed expression.
```

how transform DateTime to ToShortDateString() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [overloaded method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2d76z3ck%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that accepts a third parameter - a format string:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DateCreated", "{0:d}") %>
```

The format specifier "d" outputs the date using the short date pattern. You can [find other specifiers on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).